# Enumerating distibutions

Tags: combinations, permutation, distribution

I'm trying to create a text file with every possible distribution of 100% into n containers? So that for 4 containers, it would look something like this:

```
0.97, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01  
0.96, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02  
0.96, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01  
0.96, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01
...
```

Any ideas on a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: You seem to be making two (big) implicit assumptions, but haven't stated them.  First, you only want values to the nearest percent - if any percentage is allowable there are an infinite number of solutions, but you haven't stated your desired precision.  Second, your example shows no examples with 0% - is that explicitly disallowed?

Comment: Sorry about that. You are correct, I need the nearest whole percent simply because, like you said, there would be infinite solutions otherwise and the number of distributions would grow exponentially if it went lower then the whole percentage point. 0% is allowed, but not required because those can be generated easily from the n-1 answer.

Comment: In that case it's equivalent to an integer-based enumeration problem, and you can solve it with nested loops if the number of containers is fixed, or with recursion if the number of containers is subject to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your response in the comments above, here's a recursive solution in Ruby:

```
$resolution = 100
$res_f = $resolution.to_f

def allocate(remainder, bin_number, all_bin_values, number_of_bins)
  if bin_number >= number_of_bins
    all_bin_values << remainder / $res_f
    puts all_bin_values.join(", ")
    all_bin_values.pop
  else
    remainder.downto(1) do |i|
      if remainder - i >= number_of_bins - bin_number
        all_bin_values << i / $res_f
        allocate(remainder - i, bin_number + 1, all_bin_values, number_of_bins)
        all_bin_values.pop
      end
    end
  end
end

num_bins = (ARGV.shift || 4).to_i
allocate($resolution, 1, [], num_bins)
```

The number of containers defaults to 4, but you can override that at run time by providing a command-line argument.

**ADDENDUM**

I was surprised by your comment that a looped version "was way too slow".  All else being equal, looping should be faster than recursion and that was the case when I timed the iterative version given here:

```
resolution = 100
res_f = resolution.to_f

resolution.downto(1) do |first|
  remainder1 = resolution - first
  remainder1.downto(1) do |second|
    remainder2 = remainder1 - second
    remainder2.downto(1) do |third|
      fourth = remainder2 - third
      printf "%g, %g, %g, %g\n", first / res_f,
        second / res_f, third / res_f, fourth / res_f if fourth > 0
    end
  end
end
```

Although this is faster, the downside is that if you wanted a different number of containers the code would have to be modified accordingly by adding additional nested loops.

Comment: This works great! The nested loops was way too slow, but this is pretty quick. Thanks!